# Display BMP Files Without A Frame

Tags: java, user-interface, image

I want to devlop simple image application in java.  I need to display the image without anything around it. That is, there should be absolutely no application frame or title bar or anything else. When I open the image in this application, all I will see is the image floating on my screen.

In should when my application shold work like google picasa(desktop version).
When i install picasa and double clikc on image it shows me the full scrin image without any application window.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could set the frame to be undecorated.

```
frame.setUndecorated(true);
```

It will look and behave just as a Window container.

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.awt.Window` or `javax.swing.JWindow`?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you need a window at all.  A [SplashScreen](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) should do what you want, provided that you don't need the user to interact with the image in any way other than viewing it.  You can look at the SplashDemo.java file from the link above to get started.